# Phantom zipalign

Tags: android, zipalign

I'm trying to run zipalign from freshly installed android sdk on Ubuntu. Although you can clearly see zipalign in proper directory, running it yields "no such file or directory". I can open it in hex editor. I can list its contents with cat, but still... no such file?!

```
qus@Ubuntu:~/Dev/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/22.0.1$ ls -al
total 65400
drwxrwxr-x 4 qus qus     4096 kwi  8 19:42 .
drwxrwxr-x 3 qus qus     4096 kwi  8 19:42 ..
-rwxrwxr-x 1 qus qus  1264873 kwi  8 19:42 aapt
-rwxrwxr-x 1 qus qus   268935 kwi  8 19:42 aidl
-rwxrwxr-x 1 qus qus  3570836 kwi  8 19:42 arm-linux-androideabi-ld
-rwxrwxr-x 1 qus qus    33826 kwi  8 19:42 bcc_compat
-rwxrwxr-x 1 qus qus   473812 kwi  8 19:42 dexdump
-rwxrwxr-x 1 qus qus     2577 kwi  8 19:42 dx
-rwxrwxr-x 1 qus qus  3570836 kwi  8 19:42 i686-linux-android-ld
-rw-rw-r-- 1 qus qus  8632399 kwi  8 19:42 jack.jar
-rw-rw-r-- 1 qus qus  2948562 kwi  8 19:42 jill.jar
drwxrwxr-x 2 qus qus     4096 kwi  8 19:42 lib
-rwxrwxr-x 1 qus qus   303373 kwi  8 19:42 libbcc.so
-rwxrwxr-x 1 qus qus   802678 kwi  8 19:42 libbcinfo.so
-rwxrwxr-x 1 qus qus 15699200 kwi  8 19:42 libclang.so
-rwxrwxr-x 1 qus qus  1311060 kwi  8 19:42 libc++.so
-rwxrwxr-x 1 qus qus 22195804 kwi  8 19:42 libLLVM.so
-rwxrwxr-x 1 qus qus  1838328 kwi  8 19:42 llvm-rs-cc
-rwxrwxr-x 1 qus qus     4137 kwi  8 19:42 mainDexClasses
-rw-rw-r-- 1 qus qus      885 kwi  8 19:42 mainDexClasses.rules
-rwxrwxr-x 1 qus qus  1919720 kwi  8 19:42 mipsel-linux-android-ld
-rw-rw-r-- 1 qus qus   727899 kwi  8 19:42 NOTICE.txt
drwxrwxr-x 5 qus qus     4096 kwi  8 19:42 renderscript
-rw-rw-r-- 1 qus qus       17 kwi  8 19:42 runtime.properties
-rw-rw-r-- 1 qus qus    16509 kwi  8 19:42 source.properties
-rwxrwxr-x 1 qus qus  1228769 kwi  8 19:42 split-select
-rwxrwxr-x 1 qus qus    98040 kwi  8 19:42 zipalign
qus@Ubuntu:~/Dev/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/22.0.1$ ./zipalign 
bash: ./zipalign: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, once again for anyone who happens to stumble with same problem:

sudo apt-get install libstdc++6:i386 libgcc1:i386 zlib1g:i386 libncurses5:i386

And it works! And to think some time ago Linux users were laughing at non-descriptive Windows error messages...